# Dismissing a job ad results in a grey rectangle and a button I can't read

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

After dismissing a job ad, the follow up block of text is positioned way at the bottom with an unreadable button.

---

I was shown the following job ad and decided to dismiss it by clicking the dismiss button.

[image: Job to dismiss]

After clicking "Dismiss", this is what appeared in Firefox 47:

[image: Dismissed job]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erghhh.. yeah that's a bug. Teaches me right for only verifying in Chrome. Fix is going up now, thanks!